# Complex rank in SQL using Postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm in over my head with the SQL needed for a complex rank function. This is an app for a racing sport where I need to rank each `Entry` for a `Timesheet` based on the entry's `:total_time`.

The relevant models:

```
class Timesheet
  has_many :entries
end

class Entry
  belongs_to :timesheet
  belongs_to :athlete
end

class Run
  belongs_to :entry
end
```

An Entry's `:total time` isn't stored in the database. It's a calculated column of `runs.sum(:finish)`. I use Postgres (9.3) `rank()` function to get Entries for a given Timesheet and rank them by this calculated column.

```
def ranked_entries
  Entry.find_by_sql([
    "SELECT *, rank() OVER (ORDER BY total_time asc) 
     FROM(
       SELECT Entries.id, Entries.timesheet_id, Entries.athlete_id,   
       SUM(Runs.finish) AS total_time 
       FROM Entries 
       INNER JOIN Runs ON (Entries.id   = Runs.entry_id) 
       GROUP BY Entries.id) AS FinalRanks 
       WHERE timesheet_id =   ?", self.id])
end
```

So far so good. This returns my entry objects with a `rank` attribute which I can display on `timesheet#show`.

Now the tricky part. On a `Timesheet`, not every `Entry` will have the same number of runs. There is a cutoff (usually Top-20 but not always). This renders the rank() from Postgres inaccurate because some Entries will have a lower `:total_time` than the race winner because they didn't make the cutoff for the second heat.

**My Question:** Is it possible to do something like a `rank()` within a `rank()` to produce a table that looks like the one below? Or is there another preferred way? Thanks!

*Note: I store times as integers, but I formatted them as the more familiar MM:SS in the simplified table below for clarity*

```
| rank | entry_id  | total_time |
|------|-----------|------------|
|  1   |     6     |    1:59.05 |
|  2   |     3     |    1:59.35 |
|  3   |     17    |    1:59.52 |
|......|...........|............|
|  20  |     13    |      56.56 | <- didn't make the top-20 cutoff, only has one run.
```

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be selecting all the rows (all the runs?) in the first place. If you select the right rows--a selection which would *exclude* all the entries that had only one run--then rank() would return the result you expect. In the context of your question I guess I'd say that the preferred way would be to select the right rows *first*, after which ranking is dead simple.

Comment: I select all the rows because I want to include the entries that have only one run in the ranking. Every entry needs to be ranked regardless of the number of runs. The top 20 are ranked based on total_time, whereas 21-end are ranked off their first run finish time compared to the entire field.

Comment: How about just ranking the average instead of the total?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what "ranked off their first run finish time compared to the entire field" means, but I wrote an answer that illustrates the technique. Generate a new column that distinguishes finishers (?) from non-finishers, and use it in the ordering for `rank()`. I used a CTE; you could use a subquery if you wanted to.

Comment: Hey Gordon, I thought of the same thing and it works in most cases. The problem is if the weather conditions change between heats it throws off the rankings. It's possible that the first heat has very fast conditions and the second heat has very slow conditions. The athletes who didn't qualify for heat 2 can have a faster average than those who did qualify (and therefore should be ranked ahead)

Comment: Thanks Mike, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Assume each Timesheet has two heats. Everyone races in the first heat, and that ranking is by Run 1 finish time. Now only the top 20 (by Run 1 finish time) will qualify for heat 2, and at the conclusion that is ranked by total time of both Runs. finishers 21-end remain ranked by their first run finish time. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create a table. (Get in the habit of including CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements in all your SQL questions.)

```
create table runs (
  entry_id integer not null,
  run_num integer not null
    check (run_num between 1 and 3),
  run_time interval not null
);

insert into runs values
(1, 1, '00:59.33'),
(2, 1, '00:59.93'),
(3, 1, '01:03.27'),
(1, 2, '00:59.88'),
(2, 2, '00:59.27');
```

This SQL statement will give you the totals in the order you want, but without ranking them.

```
with num_runs as (
  select entry_id, count(*) as num_runs
  from runs
  group by entry_id
)
select r.entry_id, n.num_runs, sum(r.run_time) as total_time
from runs r
inner join num_runs n on n.entry_id = r.entry_id
group by r.entry_id, n.num_runs
order by num_runs desc, total_time asc
```

```
entry_id  num_runs  total_time
--
2         2         00:01:59.2
1         2         00:01:59.21
3         1         00:01:03.27
```

This statement adds a column for rank.

```
with num_runs as (
  select entry_id, count(*) as num_runs
  from runs
  group by entry_id
)
select 
  rank() over (order by num_runs desc, sum(r.run_time) asc), 
  r.entry_id, n.num_runs, sum(r.run_time) as total_time
from runs r
inner join num_runs n on n.entry_id = r.entry_id
group by r.entry_id, n.num_runs
order by rank asc
```

```
rank  entry_id  num_runs  total_time
--
1     2         2         00:01:59.2
2     1         2         00:01:59.21
3     3         1         00:01:03.27
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! I'll experiment with this and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks so much! One follow up. This gets all the runs in the database, but I just need the runs for one timesheet. How would you recommend I limit the runs to their entry.timesheet? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, along those lines. You definitely need that in the common table expression to get the right number of runs for each entry in the timesheet. Depending on how entry_id and timesheet_id are related, you might need the same WHERE clause in the main query, too. Or you might be able to include timesheet_id in the CTE, and join on both entry_id *and* timesheet_id in the main query.